# What are the limitations on variables in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm setting a variable in the snippet below. While it appears to be working in some cases, it fails as an invalid value in others.

```
SET VAR_TOKEN='';

// a.
SELECT $VAR_TOKEN;

// b.
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE
    STG_TABLE
WITH
    URL = 'azure://stgtableurl'
    CREDENTIALS = (azure_sas_token=$VAR_TOKEN)
```

I am seeing the variable printed using method a, but when I use the same syntax in method b I get the following error.

```
SQL compilation error: invalid value [$VAR_TOKEN] for parameter 'azure_sas_token'
```

Any ideas as to whether I am using invalid syntax in the second case or whether it isn't possible to use variables in some settings.

Comment: it seems really strange use case for variables, as the point of stages is to act as a security layer. An authorized user account creates the stage and a lower privilege can access them, but not recover the credentials. Where-as putting your credentials into the variable, allows any running SQL to recover them..
So if this is how you want to use them, it seems very wrong and dangerous. If however it's just an example carry on.

Comment: I think variables are simply only allowed in some specific places, and probably this is one of the cases where they are NOT allowed today. If it's important, feel free to raise an issue with Snowflake support, they might be able to figure out if it can be changed.